# create a random key at just one level

Tags: json, swift, firebase

In Firebase, it's possible to create a random key using .childByAutoId()

```
let newEntry = FBRef.child("category").childByAutoId()
newEntry.setValue(["someValue": true])
```

This results in a json structure like this:

```
{
  "category" : {
    "random-key-generated-by-Firebase" : {
      "someValue" : true
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering is it possible to skip the last level and arrive at a  structure like this instead?

```
{
  "category" : {
    "random-key-generated-by-Firebase" : true
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much idea about firebase but try this `newEntry.setValue(true)`

Comment: .setValue should be a simple value, not an array. The following FBRef.child("category").childByAutoId().setValue(true) will create the sturcture you mentioned

Comment: @EdmundElmer the "array" you mention is actually Swift syntax for a dictionary, which is a valid parameter to `setValue()`. But you're correct in that `setValue(true)` will result in the structure Shane requested.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Sorry, of course, it's a dictionary. I used (not correctly) "array" as a synonym for the variable that contains more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

For swift, first create a key reference

```
let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
```

Then create a childUpdate container

```
let childUpdates = ["/category/\(key)": true]
```

Finally update

```
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```